# Extracing information from a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new to Mathematica. I have created a table of real numbers. I want to create a new table that contains the set of values of $i$ such that, in my original table, the $i$th entry is greater than the $(i+1)$th entry.

For example If I had the table {1,2,5,2,9} my new table would be {3}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
lis = {1, 2, 5, 2, 9};
Flatten[Position[Greater @@@ Partition[lis, 2, 1], True]]
(* {3} *)
```

Here's an explanation:

`Partition` will group the elements in twos

```
Partition[lis, 2, 1]
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {5, 2}, {2, 9}} *)
```

Then we use `@@@` to apply a `Greater` at level 1

```
Greater @@@ Partition[lis, 2, 1]
(* {False, False, True, False} *)
```

Since `5 > 2`, `True` appears in the third position. We use `Position` to see where `True` occurs and we're done.

Answer (score 3):

```
pckpstn = Pick[Range[Length[#] - 1], Negative@Differences@#] &;
lst = {3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 9, 1};
pckpstn@lst
(* {1, 4, 5, 7} *)
```

Comment: Hey, nice to see you answering again! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using `ListConvolve` and `SparseArray`'s properties:

```
list = {1, 2, 5, 2, 9};
SparseArray[UnitStep@ListConvolve[{-1, 1}, list]]["NonzeroPositions"]
(* {{3}} *)
```